# Graph generation given number of edges and nodes

Tags: igraph

Is it possible to generate a graph in R given the number of edges and the number of nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does [erdos.renyi.game](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/erdos.renyi.game.html), that generates graphs according to the [Erdős–Rényi model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model), suit your needs?

> erdos.renyi.game(n, p.or.m, type=c("gnp", "gnm"),
>                    directed = FALSE, loops = FALSE, ...)
>
> *Arguments*
>
> **n**: The number of vertices in the graph.
>
> **p.or.m**: Either the probability for drawing an edge between two arbitrary
>   vertices (G(n,p) graph), *or the number of edges in the graph (for
>   G(n,m) graphs).*
>
> **type**: The type of the random graph to create, either gnp (G(n,p) graph) or
>   gnm (G(n,m) graph).
>
> **directed**: Logical, whether the graph will be directed, defaults to FALSE.
>
> **loops**: Logical, whether to add loop edges, defaults to FALSE. ...
>
> [...]
>
> In G(n,p) graphs, the graph has ‘n’ vertices and for each edge the
>   probability that it is present in the graph is ‘p’.
>
> *In G(n,m) graphs, the graph has ‘n’ vertices and ‘m’ edges, and the
>   ‘m’ edges are chosen uniformly randomly from the set of all possible
>   edges.* This set includes loop edges as well if the loops parameter is
>   TRUE.

Comment: Yes, it suits.
I did not realize that erdos-renyie model accepts (m , n)
Thanks