# Generating multiple random graphs in R with same number of nodes and ties?

Tags: r, social-networking

I would like to generate a large number of random graphs with the same number of nodes and ties, and use the result to find the distributions etc of the standard metrics.

I found this link for generating random graphs with a given number of nodes and ties ([Graph generation given number of edges and nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20033435/16959834)). Is there an easy way to tell R to do this 1000x or so, and combine all of those into one object, that I can then analyze? (for things like av. distance, degree, diameter, etc).

Ultimately I want to be able to use this information for comparison with an empirical network.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Code for a solution is below in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer from a friend, and it appears to work:

```
RR1 <- list()
 for(i in 1:1000) {
RR1[[i]] <- erdos.renyi.game(559,9640,type=c("gnm"),directed=FALSE,loops=FALSE)
}
number_of_edges <- sapply(RR1, gsize)
number_of_edges
```